# How to retrieve one to one chat history from Openfire using asmack android

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, asmack

Please can anyone show me the exact code for retrieving a chat history from openfire server to android client application using asmack library and XMPP protocol? In my openfire server I was enable merged Monitoring service/Open archive service and all messages successfully stored into database. But I don't know how those messages (chat history) retrieve to my client application which is building in ANDROID. What type of chat I need is one-to-one user chat (not group chat).

I am success ed to getting group chat history with help of [this](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/muc/MultiUserChat.html#join%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.DiscussionHistory,%20long%29) but i want to retrieve one to one chat history

Please if anyone can write me a code, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think server keeps such history?

Comment: @OKas Currently i have installed monitory plugin which is storing chat conversation at sever side but i don't know how to retrieving

Comment: I'm afraid standard xmpp protocol does not provide what you want. You have to implement some custom solution for accessing monitoring plugin data.

Comment: @Okas  So we need to create custom API's for retrieve user's chat history ??

Comment: I found specification XEP-0136: Message Archiving http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html . This specification is able to send message history to client and in openfire it is already implemented as Monitoring plugin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65665/discussion-between-mahi-singh-and-okas).

Comment: @Montu you got any solution for this?

Comment: @Yog Guru open fire don't provide one to one chat history

Comment: @Montu Didn't you think this is partiality ;) ? it provides history for iPhone but not for android. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
public class XMPPManager implements PacketListener {
........

   void connect(){
   //Init connection configuration
       ......
   XMPPTCPConnection xmppTCPConnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(connectionBuilder.build());
   xmppTCPConnection .connect();
   xmppTCPConnection.addSyncStanzaListener(this, null);
 }

 @Override
 public void processStanza(Stanza packet) {
   //Log.d("Log","Body - " + message.getBody());
 }
}
```